# Why commutation relations is applied in normal order for antiparticle relation ($t_1<t_2$) in wick theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator, wick-theorem

I am reading Wick theorem from "Student Friendly Quantum Field Theory" By Robert D. Kaluber. I understand how normal orderd vanishes and only contraction remains. But in page no. 205, it is stated that when $t2>t1$, then by the definition of normal order, we always put annihilation operators are always on right side of creation operator and in equation (7-84) page 205, It is accordinly as definition and only second term of equation is made normal order using commutation relations.

[image]

But in next step when $t1<t2$, it has stated that everything remains same but author have expanded the third term also (unlike previous step where it is already considered as normal order and only second term was expanded ) using commutation relations although it is already in normal order.

[image]

Why it was necessary. isn't this is already in normal order, then why it required to expand using commutation relations? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author does not want to put the operators in normal order here, but in time order, with the operators at earlier times on the right. If $t_2 < t_1$ it is already the case in his equation; if $t_1 < t_2$ he has to commute them

Comment: so it follows that he could have repeated same as he did on first equatin but choose not to and show us second method for comparison? and I don't understand if t1<t<2 , he has to commute them but why? can't he simply follow normal order as first part since anihilation operator is already at right side just as in first equation?

Comment: I do not really know what the author is doing with so few lines, nor why he introduces normal ordering. But the ordering which naturally appears when you derive the formalism is time ordering.